# Teste de api rest Nodejs com mocha e chai. Post ficando pendente

Tags: node.js, rest, testes, mocha, chai

Olá, estou aprendendo a fazer testes de api's rest e me deparei com um problema utilizando o chai e mocha, eu estava seguindo este exemplo em questão: https://medium.com/@rafaelvicio/testando-api-rest-com-mocha-e-chai-bf3764ac2797
Claro que alterando as coisas para a api que eu já tinha escrito. O problema é que o método POST está ficando pendente sempre, segundo a documentação algo pendente não significa que falhou. Porém eu gostaria de fazer esse teste passar. A minha rota está retornando um json do que foi criado, por isso não entendi direito o porque do teste não passar, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda quanto a isso?

Link para o repositório caso ajude: https://github.com/ThiagoBussola/api-games

Código da rota POST

```
router.post("/game", async (req, res) => {
    const title = req.body.title
    const year = req.body.year
    const price = req.body.price
    try {
       const gameCreated = await Game.create({
            title: title,
            year: year,
            price: price
        })
        res.json(gameCreated)
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```

Código do teste

```
describe("Teste POST game", () => {
    it("deve criar um novo jogo"), (done) => {

        let game = {
            title: "Jogo criado pelo mocha",
            year: 2020,
            price: 178
        }
        chai.request('localhost:3033')
            .post('/game')
            .send(game)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(200)
                
                done()
            })
    }
})
```

Comment: Tenta mudar o status http do teste de 200 pra 201, pois o 200 indica requisição bem sucecida, enquanto o 201 é Created.

Comment: Na repostan so seu json, voce nao deveria colocar `res.status(201).json(gameCreated)`? `201` para indicar que um recurso foi criado. Voce esta usando CORS na sua aplicacao? Quais os `allowedHeaders` permitidos? Ali no seu `.end((err, res) => {...}`, antes do `res`, seria bom voce colocar um `if(err) done(err)` pra ve o que aconteceu de errado.

Comment: Sim a aplicação está utilizando cors, quanto aos allowedHeaders, não sei responder. Enfim, coloquei o res.status(201), já tinha feito isso antes, continua vindo como pendente. E também coloquei o if(err)... sem resultados, vou colocar o link do repositório na pergunta, talvez ajude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que bom que você postou o link pro seu código completo, ficou facil de perceber o erro.

Erro simples, você fechou um parêntese antes da hora no seguinte código:

```
describe("Teste POST game", () => {
   it("deve criar um novo jogo"), (done) => { // veja o `)` antes da vírgula
    ...
   }
})
```

E veja como está o código do teste anterior:

```
describe("Teste GET games", () => {
  it("deve receber os jogos da api", (done) => {
    ...
  });
});
```

Remova este parêntese e coloque ele no final, desta forma:

```
describe("Teste POST game", () => {
  it("deve criar um novo jogo", (done) => {

    let game = {
      title: "Jogo criado pelo mocha",
      year: 2020,
      price: 178
    };
    chai.request('localhost:3033')
      .post('/game')
      .type('json')
      .send(game)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          done(err);
        }
        res.should.have.status(201);

        done();
      });
  }); // <= AQUI NO FINAL
});
```

Quando executei seu código, todos os testes passaram. Então faça seus testes e veja se resolve ;)